# Python code coverage

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py, python-coverage

```
coverage 3.4
Nose 1.1.2
Python 2.7.1
```

I have a python project structure like the below

```
root
   src #source directory
      company
          division
              pkg1
                  module1
                  module2
              pkg2
                  module1
                  module2
   test #All test files
       company
           division
              pkg1
                  test_module1
                  test_module2
```

When I run python nose I use the following snippet

```
#Run tests
#Add dependencies like cheetah, yaml, etc to the sys.path
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["NOSE_INCLUDE_EXE"] = "1"
    os.environ["NOSE_WITH_XUNIT"] = "1"
    os.environ["NOSE_WITH_COVERAGE"] = "1"
    os.environ["NOSE_COVER_PACKAGE"] = "company.division"
    nose.main()
```

My expectation was that I get clear and concise output of all packages underneath "company.division" however I get files from cheetah, yaml and their coverage which I am not interested at all. Setting the NOSE_COVER_PACKAGE does not seem to make any difference at all. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: check that you have the latest version; see this bugfix: https://github.com/Bahus/nose/commit/ddb14f0228ca94ae33d9e67785dc06bf412603f2

Comment: Sorry a bit unclear from the git commit you mentioned. Are you saying I should try nose 1.3.0?

Comment: Upgrading to nose 1.3 and coverage 3.6 fixes this. Please can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP reports that upgrading to nose 1.3 and coverage 3.6 fixes this.

See this bugfix for reference:
https://github.com/Bahus/nose/commit/ddb14f0228ca94ae33d9e67785dc06bf412603f2